# Webpacker and Asset pipeline in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webpack, ruby-on-rails-5, webpacker

I am using `webpacker` gem with `rails`.
How will it play, when we have stylesheets in `app/assets/stylesheets` and `app/javascripts/packs/frontend` .
Does it generate two different minified files? One from `webpacker` and another from the `assets pipeline`.

If it does, can I merge both to generate a single file at last?

If it doesn't, how do they resolve dependency issues like both needing the `bootstrap` library. How is this achieved? Is it by importing the dependent library twice? If so, is there a way to optimize it?

Also, if we include a style of assets files in respective controller javascript, are those styles available in `html.erb` file as well?

If so, how can I achieve this using webpacker (requiring javascript by default in `.html.erb` files)

For example, I have a folder named `employee` under `app/assets/stylesheets` which are by default add styling to the files under this folder in view files (I think rails will do this by default). Right? And company folder under `packs/stylesheets`. how do I use the `company` styles inside my `.html.erb`. Do I need to explicitly require the styles?

Comment: Why do they both need bootstrap? Can't you just use the css classes in your front-end app (e.g. react, vue.js, etc ...)